# How to install PolyBase in an availability groups architecture for high availability?

Tags: availability-groups, high-availability, polybase

**Background:** I’m designing a 2 node SQL 2019 availability groups installation hosted in VMs. 
We would have limited (single node) usage of PolyBase.  The Microsoft Docs don’t reference installation for any HA architectures. It only references how to create a PolyBase cluster. I have reviewed the Microsoft documentation, but I am unclear about the Polybase cluster vs. Windows cluster/ availability group behavior.

**Question:**
How to install PolyBase in an availability groups architecture for high availability?

**Goals:**
The goal is that PolyBase queries would still execute post failover event (without manual intervention). The decision I face is, installing 2 PolyBase head nodes (1 Polybase head node per HA node) with my current understanding.

I'm looking for any resources, articles, or advice for this situation. Specifically, how to install PolyBase in an availability groups for high availability?